# HighlightImage speed?

Tags: image-processing

I am doing a study into image processing and motion detection.  I am using various filters (`ImageDifference`, `HighpassFilter`, `Binarize`, etc.) to process the image and then `ComponentMeasurements` to determine the areas of interest.  Having found these areas, I want to indicate them on the original image - to do this I have been using the `HighlightImage` function and it is working.  However, with more than one coordinate to highlight, the function is really slow (one point = 0.15s, two or more points = 3s).  One way I thought to speed it up was to do the single coordinate update recursively, but my code has a glitch that I can't see. Any help to speed this up would be gratefully received.

```
HighlightImageFast[image_, points_] := Module[{tempImage},
  tempImage = image;
  Do[tempImage = HighlightImage[tempImage, points[[n]],
     Method -> {"CrossMarkers", 50}, "HighlightColor" -> Blue],
   {n, Length[points]}];
  tempImage
  ]
```

N.b. I'm a home use licensee and currently have version 10.0.2.0

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Mathematica.SE. While editing your question for readability I have removed your signature, as it is not a custom to sign questions and answers on this site. People can see the authors in the bottom right corner of the respective messages.

Comment: I feel like `HighlightImage` with a list should be faster than you calling `HighlightImage` n times. If that really isn't the case, I'd replace your `Do` loop with `Fold[HighlightImage[#1,#2,...options...]&,image,points]`. Maybe you can provide some data so it's easier to help.

Comment: The timings from the docs for `HighlightImage` are quite reasonable. Perhaps your images are big ...

Comment: Thanks guys,(gals).  Fold isn't updating the image either, in both cases, I get the original image without the highlights.  As for performance, if I have one point, it's 0.15s but with 2 it takes 20 times longer.  My original plan was to apply HighlightImage n times where n<20 and then do HighlightImage with the list for n>20.  The image I'm using is from a HD video so 1280 × 720.

Answer (score 9):

I would strongly discourage the iterative processing: it seems to be MUCH slower than highlighting all points in one function call. Compare for instance the following:

```
lena = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
points = RandomInteger[500, {250, 2}];

HighlightImage[lena, points]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {0.0555354, Null} *)

Fold[HighlightImage[#1, #2] &, lena, points]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {11.628, Null} *)

tempImage = lena;
Do[
  tempImage = HighlightImage[tempImage, points[[n]]],
  {n, Length[points]}
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {11.5296, Null} *)
```

As you can see, the iterative process takes roughly 200x longer than adding all highlights at once, so that will certainly NOT speed up your task.

---

Having said that, I did manage to crash both kernel and front end when trying to highlight even a few points in a much larger image (20M size). I suspect that your problems stem from the size of your images, and not from the fact that you are trying to add multiple highlights at once.

---

**Update:** Here is something else I noticed, but can't explain: the *size* of the markers influences the execution speed quite significantly! Compare the following examples:

```
fun := RepeatedTiming[HighlightImage[lena, points, Method -> {"CrossMarkers", #}];] &
fun /@ {2, 50, 150}

(*Out: {{0.061, Null}, {0.21, Null}, {1.5, Null}} *)
```

Comment: Cool info!  Thanks.  For reference, the image I was processing is from an HD video, 1280x720.  If I use the HighlightImage with a single point {123,456} then the timing is about 100 times faster than a list of lists{{123,456}}, even with the list of lists containing the same single point.
In[178]:= 
HighlightImage[lena, {123, 456}, Method -> {"CrossMarkers", 50}, 
   "HighlightColor" -> Blue]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[178]= {0.010373, Null}

In[179]:= 
HighlightImage[lena, {{123, 456}}, Method -> {"CrossMarkers", 50}, 
   "HighlightColor" -> Blue]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[179]= {0.811417, Null}